# Java update UIManager defaults and repaint components

Tags: java, uimanager

I'm using UIManager to customize some swing components like the example below,

```
UIManager.put("TextField.background", COLOR_BG);
UIManager.put("TextField.foreground", COLOR_FG);
UIManager.put("TextField.selectionBackground", COLOR_SB);
UIManager.put("TextField.selectionForeground", COLOR_SF);
UIManager.put("TextField.caretForeground", COLOR_CF);
```

Now after the application starts I want to change some colors, so I call UIManager.put again to update the UIManager, but the components aren't being updated, I tried repaint(), revalidate(), updateUI() with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe when you add your colors to the UIManager you need to wrap then in a ColorUIResource class. This allows the UIManager to think these are part of the default LAF and not a custom color so it will reset the values when you update the UI.

You will still need to use:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(...);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) for more information.

Comment: you have a big kiss from me @camickr :)